# Rails Tutorial dot org redirect_to saves but does not show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the railstutorial.org and am on chapter 7. When I add a new user the controller saves the user to the db then hangs up on the statement `redirect_to @user` then about 2 minutes later returns the url /users claiming the user already exists. What it seems like it's doing is successfully executing the create controller, saving the user, hanging up on the redirect_to call, then calling the create action with errors. Here's my code, Thanks in advance for any help

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      #flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      #render 'show'
      redirect_to user_url(@user.id)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

and the routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',              via: 'get'
  resources :users
  root 'static_pages#home'
  #match '/create',  to: 'user#show',              via: 'post'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',      via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',     via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact',   via: 'get'
```

EDIT:
So I pasted the output of the development log below. I guess the good news is it does generate an appropriate redirect at first (the redirect `Redirected to https://rails_chp3-c9-jd8001.c9.io/users/26` is what I would expect it to do... so that's good). Unfortunately the page never renders and it reloads the /user url with the POST data two minutes later. I also removed the status :see_other and return (current code updated above)

```
Started POST "/users" for 64.125.248.3 at 2014-09-23 01:36:02 +0000
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IXfkamhDHYRBHQPdMfVyp7/0zXyTONWCMfk9vO+ljHY=", "user"=>{"name"=>"aus8", "email"=>"aus8@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('aus8@gmail.com') LIMIT 1[0m
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  [1m[35mSQL (15.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Tue, 23 Sep 2014 01:36:03 UTC +00:00], ["email", "aus8@gmail.com"], ["name", "aus8"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$yYOz6cxU.mqjGlhl7Q743O0kOJJX930RmFaA1rsHjGCqz71HBIUi6"], ["updated_at", Tue, 23 Sep 2014 01:36:03 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[36m (51.8ms)[0m  [1mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to https://rails_chp3-c9-jd8001.c9.io/users/26
Completed 302 Found in 148ms (ActiveRecord: 67.7ms)


Started POST "/users" for 64.125.248.3 at 2014-09-23 01:38:03 +0000
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IXfkamhDHYRBHQPdMfVyp7/0zXyTONWCMfk9vO+ljHY=", "user"=>{"name"=>"aus8", "email"=>"aus8@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mUser Exists (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('aus8@gmail.com') LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 100ms (Views: 25.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing

```
status: :see_other and return
```

from your redirect call. Also, try looking at your logs to see if it gives you any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your create method to redirect to @user rather than user_url(@user.id)
@user.id , is most likely the integer user number.

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      #flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      #render 'show'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```